# how to remove margin from popover?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css, ionic-framework

could you please tell me how to remove margin from left of popover ? Actually I make a popover on button click But there is a margin of left I need to remove this margin of pop over .here is my code

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGMdJw
On click of button I am showing pop over

```
.cls{
  border-radius:0px!important;
  padding:0px!important;
  width:100%!important;
}
```

Comment: It's not a margin. It's the left: 6px set by the popup opener. Inspect the element.

Comment: `<ion-popover-view class="cls popover none ng-enter active ng-enter-active" style="top: 35px; left: 0px; margin-left: 0px; opacity: 1;">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people has been told its not margin, its the left value which is coming by script.

If you are looking for css solution you should try this:

```
.cls[style] {
  left: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The element `ion-popover-view` has the following style applied

```
style="top: 35px; left: 6px; margin-left: 0px; opacity: 1;"
```

So, as said by Maddy, you only need to add an override in your cls class like this

```
.cls{
     border-radius:0px!important;
     padding:0px!important;
     width:100%!important;
     left: 0px !important;
}
```